# preg_match IE8 image not showing

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I'm using this code :

```
$pageObject = get_page($page_id);  
$pageImage = ""; 
if (preg_match('/<!--\[img\](.*?)\[img\]-->/', $pageObject->post_content, $matches)){ 
   if (!empty($matches[1])){ 
       $pageImage = $matches[1]; 
   }
}
```

to get image url, and to show it I use :

```
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-139" title="" src="<?php echo $pageImage; ?>" alt="" width="" height="" />
```

It works in chrome, firefox, opera, safari, the problem is that in IE8 the image does not showing, like it doesen't exist, but in page source everything looks good.

Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: might be problem with your CSS. Because, PHP doesn't have anything to do with what happened in client.

Comment: Give us only the generated code. preg_match is executed server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `width="" height=""` from your HTML. `""` is interpreted as `0` by IE8 and thus makes the image invisible because of size 0x0.

By the way you should also remove the useless `title=""` and `alt=""`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just didn't see it :)